# Running python GUI application with PyQt and python-vlc as a service

Tags: python, qt, services, vlc

I'm trying to run a python GUI application as a service. The application is using PyQt5 and python-vlc packages. I have the following service file:

```
[Unit]
Description="Python VLC Service Test"
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /opt/experimental/vlc_pyqt.py
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

However, when playing video in the vlc window, only white screen shows up. After looking in `journalctl` I found these two errors:

```
Aug 18 16:26:27 raspberrypi python3[17754]: [83ab02c8] dbus_screensaver inhibit error: cannot connect to session bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ZeiFpFnTZO: Connection refused

Aug 18 16:26:33 raspberrypi python3[17754]: [84f28b10] mmal_codec filter error: Failed to alloc CMA buf: fmt=Z420, size=3133440
```

I think the CMA buffer error is a result of the first one. Any ideas how to fix it? The application is running just fine when run directly (not as a service).

I would like to run it as a service in order to be able to monitor the status of the application via `systemctl status vlc_pyqt.service` as the application should run all the time on the machine and to be able to gracefully restart it by `systemctl restart vlc_pyqt.service` if needed.

Comment: Possibly because the X display on `:0` doesn't belong to `pi` before anyone logs in  (running a service as a specific user does not involve a login) -- although why it opens the app at all then I dunno.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am already logged in as the `pi` user when testing this. I tried to run `sudo systemctl --user start vlc_test.service` but got `Aug 23 18:52:51 raspberrypi systemd[574]: vlc_test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'`. Any ideas how to fix this? I could not find anything explaining what could have gone wrong

Comment: Do you have any logging in vlc_pyqt.py?  If not, do not pass go, do not collect $200, etc.  `systemclt status ...` may give a bit more information.  There's kind of a pseudo/semi [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479) here, in that it's hard to see *why* you want to run this as a service.  If it's because you want it to run at boot, this is probably a bad method; you should use autostart via the DE.  If you are trying to get it to run at boot, then it seems completely pointless.

Comment: I would like to run it as a service to be able to monitor the status of the application via `systemctl status vlc_pyqt.service` as the application should run all the time on the machine and be able to gracefully restart it by `systemctl restart vlc_pyqt.service` if needed. I will add it the explanation the question.

Regarding logging: `systemctl status` showed only the last few messages and no more than `journalctl` I mentioned in the question. Those two errors do not happen when I run it the standard way. I will post a complete log from the vlc in a few hours.

Comment: *"I would like to run it as a service to be able to monitor the status of the application via systemctl status vlc_pyqt.service"* -> This is a bad reason.  Whatever you are trying to accomplish with that should be done by incorporating proper logging and controls in the application.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure you understand what I'm trying to accomplish. I have proper logging in the app itself. However, I need the app to be running at all times. If something unpredictable happens and it crashes, I need it to be started again. Therefore I want to run it as a service. I could make a cron script running pgrep for example for this but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Furthermore, when I remotely update the app, I need to stop it from running and then start it again. I can't see why that should be a bad reason.

Comment: No, I got that the first time, and I'll stick with my assertion that it would be better to incorporate this functionality into the app.   It is a bit of subjective opinion though and I won't disrupt this by pushing the point.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when trying to run VLC from a systemd unit with mmal-codec output.

Thanks to this answer I was able to make it work :

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=154020#p505537

If that's an option for you, you can put the systemd unit file in '~/.config/systemd/user/', making sure to remove the `User=` and `Environment=` directives, so with your example :

```
[Unit]
Description="Python VLC Service Test"
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /opt/experimental/vlc_pyqt.py
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

then after that, reload the daemon, enable/start the service with

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user enable yourservicefilename.service
systemctl --user  start yourservicefilename.service
```

Hope it resolves the problem for you, or can help someone out there !

EDIT: Here is my unit file for running VLC as a service with http interface :

```
[Unit]
Description=VLC http service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cvlc -I http --no-osd --http-password=foo --http-host=127.0.0.1 --http-port=8000
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Notice that in the `WantedBy=` directive, I used 'default.target' as I'm on a cli environment ( no gui/desktop ). Also notice the absence of `After=` directive in the '[Unit]' section. If you find that your service does not auto-start at boot, you should check these as it's probably due to one of those conditions not being met.

Source : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=250813